# How to draw a dot that leaves a trail

Tags: android, graphics, draw, paint, ondraw

I'm still learning Android, and I decided to download an example paint application to fiddle with that and learn a bit about how Android handles graphics/drawables/painting. The code I have shows a green and red 'V' in the upper left corner, and a red dot that follows where you touch. 
    However, I found that the screen is being redrawn each time, so I can't use it as a painting tool. It's almost as if I'm dumping a bucket of white paint over the surface and then redrawing the circle. How can I make it so that the red dot that follows your finger leaves a trail? Here's the code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
private float x;
private float y;
private int moveX;
Paint paint = new Paint();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = 
                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
private class MyCustomPanel extends View {

    public MyCustomPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);

        canvas.drawLine(moveX,10,50,50,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawLine(50, 50, 90, 10, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 3, paint);
        moveX++;
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y,3,paint);
    }
}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    v.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: check the fingerpaint sample in the samples

Answer (score 1):

For example, save the circles in an ArrayList. Make an ArrayList and save every xy coordinates from touch as a point.The following code is just from scratch, could not test it at the moment, so if anything is not working let me know and I will give a an example when I am at home.

```
    private ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>
```

Then in On Touch:

```
     Point xyPoint = new Point();
     xyPoint.x = event.getX();
     xyPoint.y = event.getY();
     pointList.add(xyPoint);
     invalidate();
```

and in onDraw, do a for-loop to get all points and draw each one:

```
      for(int i=0;i<pointList.size();i++){

          Point p = pointList.get(i);
          canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 2, paint);

       }
```

This draws circles with 2px diameter where Your finger touches. But this is just an simple example, there is a lot of more You can do and that look better. You should learn about draw on path and how to draw rects and ovales etc. Here is a good example of how to draw on path:

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/08/drawpath-on-canvas.html